# ASC CDL (SOP, SAT) with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I searched the web with no success: Is it possible to apply ASC CDL (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASC_CDL) values as a color correction with ffmpeg?

Thanks, Andy

Comment: Did you read the [ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html) ?

Comment: Yes, I did. But it looks like ASC (American Society of Cinematographers), CDL (Color Decision List) etc. are unknown to ffmpeg.

Comment: So it's probably not possible.

Comment: I was hoping ffmpeg maybe uses different terms for Slope, Offset, Power and Saturation. But maybe you are right and it is not possible.

Comment: Does the [Apply an ASC CDL (color decision list) in ffmpeg? : r/ffmpeg](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/lmsmz6/apply_an_asc_cdl_color_decision_list_in_ffmpeg/?sort=qa) discussion answer your question?

Comment: Hi David! Yep, this looks very promising, will give it a try. Thanks a lot!